# Process started from Java hangs

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to execute a c++ code from java on a remote Windows machine. In order to deal with the remote part, I have created a Web service from where the actual command is run using Runtime.exec(). The c++ exe is not being called directly from the java code. I have a batch file that eventually calls the exe.

The problem is, both java and c++ processes hang. The java code on server side does handle the output stream and error stream. Also, the c++ code is logging everything in a file on Windows. The strange thing is that, when I remove the WS call and run the java code on server side as a standalone java program, it succeeds. Here is the java code:

```
public class RunCPlusPlusExecutable {

public int runExecutable() {
    int exitValue = 0;

    try {
        Process p = null;
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        System.out.println("About to execute" + this + rt);
        p = rt.exec("c:/temp/execcplusplus.bat");
        System.out.println("Process HashCode=" + p.hashCode());

        StreamProcessor errorHandler = new StreamProcessor(p.getErrorStream(), "Error");
        StreamProcessor outputHandler = new StreamProcessor(p.getInputStream(), "Output");

        errorHandler.start();
        outputHandler.start();
        exitValue = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit value : " + exitValue);
        if (exitValue == 0)
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        else
            System.out.println("FAILURE");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return exitValue;
}

class StreamProcessor extends Thread {

    private InputStream is = null;
    private String type = null;
    private InputStreamReader isr = null;
    private BufferedReader br = null;
    private FileWriter writer = null;
    private BufferedWriter out = null;

    StreamProcessor(InputStream is, String type) {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            writer = new FileWriter("*******path to log file********");
            out = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Date date = new Date();
                out.write("[" + type + "]: " + date + " : " + line);
                out.newLine();
            }
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (isr != null)
                    isr.close();
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any idea what is causing the problem and how to debug it? Please note that I won't be able to debug the c++ code.

Thanks

**Update 1:**
Here are some more details... 
The WS server is running from some admin user. And I have been running the standalone java program from some other user.
**It seems that the c++ executable is giving referenced memory error while executing from WS call. There are pop-ups citing the error with OK and Cancel buttons. **

**Update 2:**
The tomcat server where the WS is deployed is running as a Windows NT service. Can that be the cause of the error? If yes, how to resolve this?

Comment: is the c++ program waiting on input from stdin (console) ?

Comment: I don't think so because when I run the batch it doesn't ask for any input...

Comment: try running `cmd /c c/temp/execcplusplus.bat` instead of `c/temp/execcplusplus.bat`. btw is `c/temp/execcplusplus.bat` path correct? shouldn't it be `c:/` in front of it instead of `c/`

Comment: thanks csoroiu... i tried that... but the result is same... please see my update...

Comment: Probbably should be c:/ as mentioned. Could you try ProcessBuilder ?

Comment: yeah... it is c:/... sorry for the typo

Comment: It's probably buffering  by the BufferedReader that is messing things up. Try creating your BufferedReader like "new BufferedReader(isr,1)" which will effectively turn off buffering.

Comment: Yeah, the popup dialog is what is hanging the whole thing up. Unless there is some way to keep that from happening, you cannot control the C++ code programmatically. Are there command line options in the C++ to avoid using a dialog?

Comment: Hi Zagrev... I think the c++ code itself is not giving the popup... its the runtime environment that gives it... The popup says... "The instruction at 0x05473030 referenced memory at 0x000001d4. The memory could not be read"...